# Checkbox custom style not display properly in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css

I am working on a custom checkbox. It's working well in Chrome, Mozilla, and Safari but not displaying properly in IE 11.

[image: in this image checkbox is not properly displayed in IE 11]

I have tried most in Stack Overflow to find answer related to this issue but I can't find one so I am asking here. See this code example:

https://jsfiddle.net/spvkomd1/

```css
.chk_bx label {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.custom_chk_bx {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.chk_bx {
  padding-right: 20px;
}


/* Base for label styling */

.custom_chk_bx [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
.custom_chk_bx [type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

.custom_chk_bx [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label,
.custom_chk_bx [type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


/* checkbox aspect */

.custom_chk_bx [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label:before,
.custom_chk_bx [type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 23px;
  height: 24px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: rgb( 192, 209, 218);
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: none;
}


/* checked mark aspect */

.custom_chk_bx [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label::after,
.custom_chk_bx [type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  color: #0b8fcf;
  content: "✔";
  font-size: 16px;
  left: 5px;
  line-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}


/* checked mark aspect changes */

.custom_chk_bx [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.custom_chk_bx [type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="dtl_row">
  <div class="custom_chk_bx inpt_blk">
    <span class="chk_bx">
       <input type="checkbox" id="test1" name="" value="">
       <label for="test1">Compliant With PF(India)</label>
    </span>
    <span class="chk_bx">
       <input type="checkbox" id="test2" name="" value="" checked="checked">
       <label for="test2"> With ESIC(India)</label>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add your code like js fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/spvkomd1/ pls see this.

Comment: which version to use IE ?

Comment: internet explore 11

Answer (score 0):

> Hi Riddhi,
>
> When I Checked your JSfiddle code it's look perfect ([IE 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pioOD.png)).
>
> And if you want same tick look on all browser then set font-family.

**In Chrome**

```
*font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe
 UI",Roboto,Oxygen,Ubuntu,Cantarell,"Fira Sans","Droid Sans","Helvetica
 Neue",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI
 Symbol";*
```

Answer (score 0):

Add line-height this class

```
.custom_chk_bx [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label::after, .custom_chk_bx [type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
    color: #0b8fcf;
    content: "✔";
    font-size: 16px;
    left: 5px;
    line-height: 16px; /*Add This */
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
```